# Optimal code to check and append an item in a list if present in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

These are my inputs, pretty-printed for better readability

```
input1 = [{
    "ID": "1",
    "SequenceNum": 1
   },
   {
    "ID": "2",
    "SequenceNum": 2
   },
   {
    "ID": "3",
    "SequenceNum": 3
   },
   {
    "ID": "4",
    "SequenceNum": 4
   }]
input2 = ['4', '1']
```

The values contained in `input2` are basically the values of the `'ID'` key seen in `input1`

The output will be a list of dictionaries where `input1[index]['ID'] == input2[index_element]`.

Expected output -> `[{"ID": "4","SequenceNum": 4},{"ID": "1","SequenceNum": 1}]`

I have solved this using the following lines of code:

```
match_list = []

for idx,val in enumerate(input1):
    match_list.append(val['ID'])

return_list = []

for idx,val in enumerate(input2):
    if val in match_list:
        get_idx = match_list.index(val)
        return_list.append(input1[get_idx])
```

While it works it doesn't feel like the most optimal nor the cleanest way to write code. I apologize for the basic question, I am not a very experienced programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you could do:

```
s = set(input2)
res = [d for d in input1 if d["ID"] in s]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'ID': '1', 'SequenceNum': 1}, {'ID': '4', 'SequenceNum': 4}]
```

This has an expected linear complexity.

If the order with respect to `input2` needs to be kept, you could do:

```
lookup = {d["ID"]: d for d in input1}
res = [lookup[i] for i in input2 if i in lookup]
print(res)
```

This also has an expected linear complexity.